# hciconfig returns the staus from where

Tags: bluetooth

`hciconfig -a` returns a status of the device (UP RUNNING, DOWN etc) - is that status available as a file to read from somewhere? I want to monitor it through `monit`.

I have looked through the `/sys/class/bluetooth/hci0/` tree without success.